# React-Router Redirect from a portal not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-portal

I'm working on a Twitch clone application for React practice, and I'm in the process of creating a modal popup for when users want to delete a video stream. Basically they have a list of streams, they click a delete button on one of the streams, and that opens a modal  using `ReactDOM.createPortal`

Here is the delete button

```
import React from "react";

import Modal from "../Modal";

const StreamDelete = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Modal />
    </>
  );
};

export default StreamDelete;
```

Here is the code for the Modal

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Modal = () => {

  
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      className="ui dimmer modals visible active"
      onClick={ () => {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      } }
    >
      <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
        <div className="header">Delete Stream</div>
        <div className="content">
          Are you sure you want to delete this stream?
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="ui primary button">Delete</button>
          <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.querySelector("#modal")
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

[image: how the modal looks]

This modal can only be viewed on the React-Router Route **/streams/:id/delete**

My expected behavior is that when I click on the dark background my `onClick` function there should return the `<Redirect to="/">` which should therefore close the Modal window, because it is not being rendered in that route.

The behaviour that i'm getting is that clicking on the dark background is not redirecting, although i'm not receiving any errors either.

For additional context the GIT repo for this project is here [Glitch Client](https://github.com/ncoughlin/react-streams-client)

And I have an extensive set of notes on all parts of this project so far here [Ncoughlin: Tag Twitch Clone](https://ncoughlin.com/tags/twitch-clone)

Comment: That isn't how a `Redirect` component works, it needs to be returned as part of the renderable JSX, not as the return value of an `onClick` callback. If you are able to access the `history` route prop, or pass it to the modal, then you can imperatively issue a navigation. Alternatively you can create some component state that a redirect should occur and conditionally render the `Redirect`. Can you provide the router code so we may see how `StreamDelete` is rendered?

Comment: Yes, the router is available here: [App.js](https://github.com/ncoughlin/react-streams-client/blob/master/src/components/App.js)

Comment: I was specifically trying to avoid manually touching the history prop for the reasons covered in this post here [ncoughlin:programmatic navigation](https://ncoughlin.com/posts/react-router-programmatic-navigation/)

Comment: And what are the reasons listed in that link? I don't see any there.

Comment: I should have linked directly here, This was the article I read that made sense to me as a good example to avoid the history prop [ui.dev: programmatically navigate](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-programmatically-navigate/)

Comment: Here is a short quote from that article: Again, the reason for this is because it aligns exactly with the principles of React itself.

<Redirect /> is

    Composable ✅
    Declarative ✅
    user event -> state change -> re-render ✅

Comment: Yep. But you return Redirect from onClick instead example return Redirect from render.

Comment: Avoiding using the `history` prop to issue navigation actions as a side-effect versus a `Route` or `Redirect` component seem entirely up to opinion. IMO they both have their valid use-cases and to entirely use one or the other will lead to odd code patterns (like below) where you need to save some state first, wait for component to update and rerender, *and then* navigate. It's a wasted render cycle. That article is 2+ years old, and react components have the concept of effects now, which don't necessarily align with always updating *some* state first in order to do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on this. I'm just a beginner so this is all helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

Since `StreamDelete` is directly rendered by a `Route` component

```
<Route path="/streams/:id/delete" exact component={StreamDelete} />
```

## Solution

It is passed route props, and thusly has access to the `history` prop. You can consume this in `StreamDelete` and pass a callback to the modal to take the action you want.

```
const StreamDelete = ({ history }) => {
  const doRedirect = () => history.replace("/");
  return (
    <>
      <Modal onDelete={doRedirect} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Modal

```
const Modal = ({ onDelete }) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      className="ui dimmer modals visible active"
      onClick={onDelete}
    >
      <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
        <div className="header">Delete Stream</div>
        <div className="content">
          Are you sure you want to delete this stream?
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="ui primary button">Delete</button>
          <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.querySelector("#modal")
  );
};
```

## Alternative

Declarative Implementation if you want to avoid using the `history` prop for some reason.

Use some "redirect" state in the modal conditionally render a `Redirect`.

```
const Modal = () => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
  
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      className="ui dimmer modals visible active"
      onClick={() => setRedirect(true)}
    >
      <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
        <div className="header">Delete Stream</div>
        <div className="content">
          Are you sure you want to delete this stream?
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="ui primary button">Delete</button>
          <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.querySelector("#modal")
  );
};
```

## Suggested Alternative

Don't couple app behavior with presentational (i.e. Modal) components. Conditionally render a `Redirect` in `StreamDelete` upon some "confirmation" from the modal.

```
const StreamDelete = () => {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);
  
  return confirm ? (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  ) : (
    <Modal onConfirm={() => setConfirm(true)} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to get this to function by following the example in the article linked above. Convert to component, create a state, use the click handler to trigger a helper function that set's state to conditionally render the redirect.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Modal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toDashboard: false,
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      toDashboard: true
    }))
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.toDashboard === true) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      
      <div
        className="ui dimmer modals visible active"
        onClick={ this.handleClick }
      >
        <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
          <div className="header">Delete Stream</div>
          <div className="content">
            Are you sure you want to delete this stream?
          </div>
          <div className="actions">
            <button className="ui primary button">Delete</button>
            <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>,
      document.querySelector("#modal")
    );
  }
  
};

export default Modal;
```

This technique was explained in this article [ui.dev : programmatic navigation](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-programmatically-navigate/)